# How do I stop a video from playing when switching to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, youtube

I have this could which allows me to play a youtube video within my ipad app. However when I switch views, the video does not stop playing in the background. Do I have to add anything to make it stop playing when the views switch?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/123456"];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoURL];
    UIWebView * YoutubeVideo = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

    YoutubeVideo.frame = CGRectMake(176,243,556,335);

    [self.view addSubview:YoutubeVideo];

    [YoutubeVideo loadRequest:requestObj];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self.YoutubeVideo loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
    }
```

This should work.When the view disappears, webview have nothing and when view comes back in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad, load the video again, keep the youtubeVideo webview as a property so that you can access it in every method.

Comment: Or if you just want to pause video and all, better use an MPMoviePlayerController instead of a video in webview.

Comment: I added this but for some reason it didn't do anything.. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: are you switching views as tabs or your are pushing a VC ?

Comment: Try, [self.YoutubeVideo loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")]; instead!

Comment: When I try that I get an error that says: "Implicit declaration of function 'NSURLRequestFromString' in invalid in C99"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18642/discussion-between-jeff-and-amogh-talpallikar)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has provided its player called YTPlayer. You can import its library, and use as follow:

1. In your podfile, you should have this line:

   pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.4"
2. In the ViewController.h file you have to:

a. Import the YTPlayer.h file:

```
#import "YTPlayer.h"
```

b. Define this within the interface:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;
```

3. In the ViewController.m file, you have this function:

   - (void)viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated {

     [self.playerView stopVideo];

   }

It works for me.